# Pass year in formula

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, formula

My formula sets the month and year in a column:

```
if {OFPR.Code} = "2016-01" then
    {INV1.Quantity}
else
    0
```

It works unless I pass the year via a parameter. In that case it zeroes out:

```
if {OFPR.Code} = "{?ParamYear@select * from OPID}-01" then
    {INV1.Quantity}
else
    0
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure this code  "{?ParamYear@select * from OPID}-01" is running in formula?

Comment: On Further investigation its not. Its returning {?ParamYear@select * from OPID}-01. Thanks for the tip to check. I will look into why

Answer (score 0):

Something looks odd about your parameter field {?ParamYear@select * from OPID} but if it is returning a year for you then you just need to concatenate the data together properly. This should work.

```
if {OFPR.Code} = "{?ParamYear@select * from OPID}" & "-01" then
    {INV1.Quantity}
else
    0
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately still the same result, {?ParamYear@select * from OPID}-1
. If i only use {?ParamYear@select * from OPID} it returns the correct parameter which was entered but as a string, 2016. When i try and join something onto the end this is where we have a problem.